# How to Make a Dictionary Accept any Integer to Trigger a Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

Let's say you have the following code:

```
def statementz():
    print("You typed in", number)


digits = {
  56 : statementz
}

while True:
  try:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
  except TypeError:
    print("Invalid. Try again.\n")
    continue
  else:
    digits.get(number, lambda : None)()
    break
```

I am wondering if there is a way so that one could allow the dictionary to trigger the "statementz" function if the variable "number" holds the value of any integer/float, and not just the integer that is given in the (rather sloppy) example above.

Is it possible to do this? Thank you in advance for any guidance given!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any number to be passed to `statementz()`, you can simply call it directly after validating it as a number. A dict is only useful if you want to map different numbers to different functions, which is not the behavior you are asking for. Also note that your `statementz()` should take a number as a parameter since you want to print the number in the function:

```
def statementz(number):
    print("You typed in", number)

while True:
  try:
    number = float(input("Enter a number: "))
    statementz(number)
  except TypeError:
    print("Invalid. Try again.\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still working on seeing the functions of different things in programming clear xD I tend to overcomplicate things much too often without considering a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Without try-except:

**Try using:**

```
def statementz(number):
    print("You typed in", number)

while True:
    number = input("Enter a number: ")
    if number.isdigit():
        statementz(number)
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid. Try again.\n")
```

**Example Output:**

```
Enter a number: Apple
Invalid. Try again.

Enter a number: 12ab
Invalid. Try again.

Enter a number: --41-
Invalid. Try again.

Enter a number: 24
You typed in 24
```

Comment: Beware that `.isdigit()` will reject the decimal point and minus sign, so it only really works for whole numbers. The try/except approach is more general. One could also try a regex.

Comment: @gilch I know that but just i think the OP should allow that to happen